# How to calculate the sample size if there is no previous studies have the same study design?

Tags: sample-size

I am currently calculating my sample size based on the effect size from previous studies. Can our experimental designs be different? That is, the previous study used a two-way ANOVA to calculate TTFF, with the interaction effect being between the diagnosis group and object type, and the effect size was 0.332. I am using a two-way repeated measures ANOVA to calculate the change in TTFF over time, with the interaction effect being between the diagnosis group and time. Can I use 0.332 as the effect size in G*Power to calculate my sample size?